# Can I add a custom field to a field set used by a Visualforce page from a managed package?

Tags: managed-package, fieldsets

As a managed package owner, I have a VF page rendering  an object containing a field set with 5 fields (using dynamic bindings similar to http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm)

Once this managed package is deployed into a customer's environment they may add custom fields to the object. Will they be able to add these custom fields to the field set and have my VF page display them?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if the field is custom to their org then they can add it to the field set.

If the field is part of your managed package they can only add it if it is in the Available Fields list when you create / update your package..