# Can't add certain fields to field set

Tags: managed-package, fieldsets, field-service-lightning

I'm working with a client org that uses the Field Service Lightning managed package. FSL includes a few fieldsets we can edit in order to make sure certain fields show on certain pages.

The FSL Service object has one such fieldset called Service Lightbox. When I go to edit the fieldset, I see a whole bunch of my custom fields and many of the fields that came with FSL. I am able to add fields pointing to related objects such as Account, Asset and Resource. However for whatever reason the related Contact does not appear as an option. For a different FSL fieldset, Services List Columns, there is no such issue and I'm indeed able to add Contact to the fieldset. Similarly if I create my own fieldset I can add Contact to it.

Is there anything I'm missing here? What drives the available fields I can choose to add to a fieldset? It really is essential to add Contact here and it does not make sense that it's unavailable.

Comment: Bump? I really never figured this out and it's really irritating me.

Answer (score 5):

Field sets in managed packages require the developer to explicitly mark each one as eligible to be added to the field set. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/63416/55332

There is an idea to be able to set this at the object level, since many managed package owners overlook this. 
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000aKz1AAE